# Networking blocking to non-blocking, only threads as option?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, irc

So I've been using C# for a day now. The first application I am writing is a simple console-based IRC-Client, however it is harder then I thought. Since I'm reading from two streams: console & irc-server I need some kind of non-blocking I/O.

At the moment I've got the following code:

```
while (((sInput = sr.ReadLine()) != null) || ((uuInput = Console.ReadLine()) != null))
                {
                    // stuff
                }
```

However, this will always execute sInput, because .ReadLine() is blocking and so eventually return True at the end, so the second block of the OR will never get executed.

What is the solution to this? Implementing it myself with threads? I can't seem to find any NIO library in the standard C# library. I prefer to have a small, clean solution because I don't want to overcomplicate this program.

Any help would be very nice. Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI: what you want to look for is handling IO with async calls; you do not want non-blocking sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You've definitely jumped in at the deep end when it comes to learning C#. Based on the question tags you set I assume you are after help more with the networking side than the direct input / output issues. It would be fair to say that networking in whatever language you use is definitely non trivial. Perhaps the best way to help you is to point you in the direction of an example which demonstrates what you are trying to implement. [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/wiki/Home), an open source network library has as one of it's examples a chat application, [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/20123ae7cf23/ExamplesConsole/BasicSend.cs) (only 11 lines long). If you have any questions after having had a look let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using asynchronous operations, like `BeginRead()`, but that would mean using `Stream` instead of `StreamReader`.

So, I think that in your case, yes, it would be easiest if you created another thread, and performed the other blocking call there. But if you do that, don't forget to synchronize access to any resources that are shared by the two threads, probably by using a `lock`.